# calling spyder from ubuntu bash in windows 11 causing error

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, spyder, wsl-2

I am using Win 11

I installed wsl2 and ubuntu bash

i also installed spyder but everytime i try to run it i get error

```
asmgx@DELLG3:~$ spyder
/home/asmgx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:122: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.23ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/home/asmgx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:122: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.36ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0.0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted
```

I googled and tried different solutioins proposed

such as

```
pip install spyder

pip install --upgrade spyder

pip install PyQt5

export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
```

but non worked

any one know how can i get spyder running?

Comment: pip install PyQt5==5.10 has worked for me in the past. Not guaranteeing it will work though... you could also try using miniconda instead of pip to manage your packages bc spyder plays nicer with conda I think.

Comment: *`could not connect to display :0.0`* -- Are other X apps working in your WSL2/WSLg environment?  Something like a simple xterm, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spyder document  [Frequently Asked Questionsits](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html?highlight=run%20cell#frequently-asked-questions) explain how to connect.

> If you already installed Spyder on your Windows machine, you do not need to reinstall it on a WSL2-based Linux environment if your code must run there.
> Instead, just install **`Miniconda inside WSL2`** and create a new conda environment (or use an existing conda- or virtualenv), then **install Spyder-Kernels** into that environment with e.g. **`conda install spyder-kernels`**. You must manually install ipython_genutils with e.g. **conda install ipython_genutils**

> To start a Spyder kernel, from your Linux terminal run

```
python -m spyder_kernels.console --matplotlib="inline" --ip=127.0.0.1 -f=~/remotemachine.json &
```

> It will run the kernel as a subprocess and create a file named remotemachine.json in your WSL home folder.

> Finally, under the options menu of Spyder’s IPython Console, select Connect to an existing kernel as described in Using external kernels. Insert the absolute path of remotemachine.json into the Connection file field. If you mapped W: as mentioned in above note, the path should be W:/home/username/remotemachine.json. A new console will open in Spyder, running in the Linux environment. Try running os.system('ls -la') and see if it lists your WSL home folder. If you run exit() from Spyder, the kernel running on Linux will be stopped.

You can fallow this [url for any update](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html?highlight=run%20cell#install-wsl2).

At my end its work perfactly.